# how to implement html content editor in android application

Tags: android, android-webview

i am receiving html from server and need to show it to user with simple styles (like bold, italic etc) and user should be able to edit it and impart similar style in it. i used webview, but it is not editable. I have seen some prev ques about rich text editor, but none of them are clear about what to do, or i could not understand as i am a newbie in this field. Thanks in advance. Here **data** is a string which is recieved from server, it contains html tags within. I need an editor which can add new text, edit prev one, bold/unbold selected text and some similar functions

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setEnabled(true);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html",
            "utf-8", null);
```